# How can I activate and deactivate styles in component from typescript from another component in Angular 6?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular6

I have in my `app.component.ts`

```
this.renderer.listenGlobal('window', 'scroll', (event) => {
            const number = window.scrollY;
            if ((number > 150 || window.pageYOffset > 150) && this.location.prepareExternalUrl(this.location.path()) == '/') {
                // I want to activate here style .nav-item .nav-link:not(.btn) in navbar.component.html
                navbar.classList.remove('navbar-transparent');
            } else {
                // I want to deactivate here style .nav-item .nav-link:not(.btn) in navbar.component.html
                navbar.classList.add('navbar-transparent');
            }
        });
```

In `navbar.component.html` I have

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!isDocumentation() && !isMain() && !isCloud() && !isView()">
          <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="Follow us on Twitter" data-placement="bottom"
             href="https://example-link.com" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            <p class="d-lg-none">Twitter</p>
          </a>
        </li>
```

I would like to activate and deactivate styles automatically from `navbar.component.scss`

```
  .nav-item .nav-link:not(.btn){
      color: black;
      border-color: black;
  }
```

in `app.component.ts` in this place

```
        // I want to activate here style .nav-item .nav-link:not(.btn) in navbar.component.html
        navbar.classList.remove('navbar-transparent');
    } else {
        // I want to deactivate here style .nav-item .nav-link:not(.btn) in navbar.component.html
        navbar.classList.add('navbar-transparent');
    }
```

Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the ngClass.

In the html:

```
<inptut [ngClass]="'navbar-transparent', boolean" />
```

What this will do is add the style if the boolean is true and remove it when the boolean is false. If you are using a parent child structure you can use @Input or @Output to set the value of boolean. Otherwise you can use a shared service.

Sources: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction